# woocommerce PayPal link error - comma instead of dot

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

i am using WooCoomerce and Wordpress in their newest versions. On top i have German Market installed. I enter my prices like 24,99€. The decimal position is separated by an "," and the thousand separator by an "."
I Also tried to set the decimal to "." and the thousand to "" (empty)

The payment gateway is PayPal. After getting to the checkout and clicking on the "Pay with PayPal" link the following error appears:

`The link you have used to enter the PayPal system contains an incorrectly formatted item amount.`

I narrowed it down to the semicolon/comma within `amount_1=49,98`
(`...quantity_1=1&amount_1=49,98&item_number_1=5381`)

Comma is not working in the link. If i change it to an dot it works.

Unfortunately i can not find any place in the whole code or Wordpress Settings Area where i can edit the PayPal behavior. 
Does any one have any idea how to change the "," to a "." within the PayPal link?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the issue persist if you disable the German market plugin?

Comment: @helgatheviking yes it does

Comment: Do you have the currency options set in the WooCommerce settings? Which version of PayPal are you using? I just switched my test site to comma decimals and cannot reproduce this; the link generated by PayPal standard (included with WooCommerce) looks like `webscr?cmd=_flow&SESSION=ABCD` and the GET variables aren't human readable.

Comment: Yes i have the option set in WooCommerce. Where can i find the PayPal version? It is the one integrated in woocommerce.

Comment: If you didn't add a separate PayPal plugin then you are using the PayPal standard that is included with WooCommerce; the same version I just tested with [here](https://wordpress-helgatheviking.c9.io/product/ship-your-idea/?attribute_pa_color=black). I would suggest that you disable all other plugins, and switch to the Twenty Sixteen theme. I can only guess that you have a conflict of some kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited the file in 
`plugins/woocommerce/includes/gateways/paypal/includes/class-wc-gateway-paypal-request.php` on line **311**:

FROM:
`$this->line_items[ 'amount_' . $index ]      = (float) $amount;`

TO:
`$this->line_items[ 'amount_' . $index ]      = (string) str_replace(",", ".", $amount);`

Now every comma is converted into a dot and everything works :)
**IMPORTANT**
You may have to reset this if there is a woocommerce update.

Answer (score 1):

Try hook in your function file without change core file of woo commerce plugin by use of default woo commerce hook for Paypal,

```
'woocommerce_paypal_args'

your_function_name($array){
    global $woocommerce;
    //Edit your price to send to Paypal

    return $array;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_paypal_args','your_function_name',10,1);
```

Comment: the correct answer is actually my own one - yours is just the way to make it save for updates ;)

Comment: your answer may be right but it is better to extend hook rather than change into core file of plugin.